# What would be the equivalent for recoil effect for jotai?

Tags: react-native, jotai

I am trying to convert my recoil code to jotai. However, i'm having trouble understanding effects for jotai. How do i use recoil in jotai? I know they have jotai-effect but seems like its not working right

My origin recoil code

```
  key: 'user',
  default: null,
  effects: [storageEffect, userEffect],
});

function storageEffect({setSelf, onSet, resetSelf}) => {
//code
}

function userEffect({setSelf}) => {
//code
}
```

What i did so far in jotai

```
const userEffect = atomEffect(() => {
  storageEffect
  userEffect
});

export const user = atom<any>(get => {
  get(firebaseUserEffect);
});
```

what is the equivalent jotai code for recoil that has effects with setSelf, onSet and resetSelf?

Answer (score 0):

The docs for jotai-effect are inadequate and do not give a full simple example of how to activate an effect when state changes.

This is the recipe I use when I need to run third party code conditional on an atom value (I don't even bother using jotai-effects):

```js
const counterAtom = atom(
  5, // <-- default value
  (get, set, newVal) => {
    // Start side effect code here
    if (newVal < 0) alert('negative counter value!');
    // End side effect code
    set(counterAtom, newVal); // <-- update self
  }
);

// If you need your effect to run on mount, then hook into the onMount method as follows:
counterAtom.onMount = (setSelf) => {
  setSelf(5); // This is duplication of setting the default value (I've not found a cleaner way to avoid this repetition)
  return () => {
    // Cleanup code goes here if needed
  };
};
```